# How do I set up terminal and emacs on mac os to have brackets and meta key?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

**Problem:**

No simultaneous availability of the `meta` key and brackets in emacs in the terminal app + european keyboard layout.

**Description:**

```
(setq mac-option-modifier nil
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

In the `init.el` maps the meta key to `cmd` for emacs on mac os. This works fine in the GUI emacs. But in the terminal it doesn't. `cmd-f` will search the terminal. Others like `cmd-x` that are no terminal specific bindings won't do anything.

The default solution to enable the `meta` key is to enable the *Use Option as Meta key* option of the terminal app => `alt` as meta key. However this *overwrites* many important system bindings like brackets.

Is there a way to set up terminal and emacs to have both brackets and the meta key on a european (German) keyboard?

This question has beed asked a few times. But the questions and answers are 4-6 years old and don't work (as far as I tried).

I hope new versions of mac os and emacs may provide a solution.

Comment: Are you sure emacs on Terminal uses the same configuration as your GUI Emacs? Which Emacs are you using? Also try 'which emacs' on the command line.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure they use the same configuration. It's 25.1.1. It's installed using Homebrew.

Comment: In my init.el for the emacs-app port installed via macports I am using the variables  `ns-command-modifier 'meta`, `ns-alternate-modifier nil` and `ns-use-mac-modifier-symbols  nil` to achieve your desired behaviour with a german keyboard.

Comment: Does your setup also work when you open emacs inside the terminal? For me it doesn't

Comment: I get it. It looks to me as if the terminal handles the command key so that you have to use `ESC` instead. With my setup `alt` is available for accessing the special characters. For further help you need to provide more information, e.g. which emacs, which environment etc.

Comment: Thanks, using the `exc` key is enough of a workaround for me at this point. Even though I would be interested in a general answer. 

I'm not sure what more information you need. I installed it via homebrew and asked how to set up the key mapping such that it works when opened in the terminal app.